# pandas dropna giving different results when applied to a dataframe with 2 columns or the columns as independednt dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm using the following public dataset to practice linear regression:

https://www.kaggle.com/theforcecoder/wind-power-forecasting

I tried to do a least squares regression using numpy polynomial, and I ran into issues because the columns had nan values

applying dropna to the dataframe from where i extract the columns does not have an effect. I tried both using in_place=True and defining a new dataframe, but neither works:

```
LSFitdDf = BearingTempsCorr[['WindSpeed', 'BearingShaftTemperature']]
LSFitdDf = LSFitdDf[['WindSpeed', 'BearingShaftTemperature']]

WindSpeed = BearingTempsCorr['WindSpeed']
BearingShaftTemperature = BearingTempsCorr['BearingShaftTemperature']

print(len(WindSpeed))
print(len(BearingShaftTemperature))
```

and

```
LSFitdDf = BearingTempsCorr[['WindSpeed', 'BearingShaftTemperature']].dropna()
LSFitdDf = LSFitdDf[['WindSpeed', 'BearingShaftTemperature']]

WindSpeed = BearingTempsCorr['WindSpeed']
BearingShaftTemperature = BearingTempsCorr['BearingShaftTemperature']

print(len(WindSpeed))
print(len(BearingShaftTemperature))
```

Both produce the same output (length of both columns=323)

However, applying dropna to the columns themselves does drop rows:

```
WindSpeed = BearingTempsCorr['WindSpeed'].dropna()
BearingShaftTemperature = BearingTempsCorr['BearingShaftTemperature'].dropna()
```

results in lengths=(316, 312)

However this introducces a new problem: regression cannot be applied because x and y have different lengths

What is going on here?

Comment: I have already tried resetting the index in the 'whole' dataframe too

Comment: i will read through it. That's what i initially did, produces the same result (of not dropping rows). That whole cell is a 'debug' cell i setup specifically to find out where the issue is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code:

```
WindSpeed = BearingTempsCorr['WindSpeed'] 
BearingShaftTemperature = BearingTempsCorr['BearingShaftTemperature']
```

You use `BearingTempsCorr`, but you should use `LSFitdDf` (where you saved dropna values).

```
WindSpeed = LSFitdDf['WindSpeed'] 
BearingShaftTemperature = LSFitdDf['BearingShaftTemperature']
```

P.S. You also have redundant line, which just copies the `LSFitdDf` into the same variable.

```
LSFitdDf = LSFitdDf[['WindSpeed', 'BearingShaftTemperature']]
```

P.P.S. The most clear way to get the whole dataset but drop lines with NA values in desired columns is

```
BearingTempsCorr.dropna(subset=['WindSpeed', 'BearingShaftTemperature'])
```

Comment: Well thanks. the only part i needed was the referencing of a different df after the dropna :facepalm: . All the ohter redundant lines were added so i could closely find where i was making a mistake (obviously didn't work)